# Escaping query strings with wget --mirror

Tags: linux, wget, mirroring

I'm using `wget --mirror --html-extension --convert-links` to mirror a site, but I end up with lots of filenames in the format `post.php?id=#.html`. When I try to view these in a browser it fails, because the browser ignores the query string when loading the file. Is there any way to replace the `?` character in the filenames with something else?

---

The answer of `--restrict-file-names=windows` worked correctly. In conjunction with the flags `--convert-links` and `--adjust-extension`/`-E` (formerly named `--html-extension`, which also works but is deprecated) it produces a mirror that behaves as expected.

```
wget  --mirror --adjust-extension --convert-links --restrict-file-names=windows http://www.example
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

See the `--restrict-file-names` option. While not exactly intended for this particular purpose, `--restrict-file-names=windows` will probably help you along:

> --restrict-file-names=modes
>
> Change which characters found in remote URLs must be escaped during generation of local filenames. [...]
>
> When "windows" is given, Wget escapes the characters \, |, /, :, ?, ", *, <, >, and the control characters in the ranges 0--31 and 128--159.  In addition to this, Wget in Windows mode uses + instead of : to separate host and port in local file names, and uses @ instead of ? to separate the query portion of the file name from the rest.  Therefore, a URL that would be saved as www.xemacs.org:4300/search.pl?input=blah in Unix mode would be saved as www.xemacs.org+4300/search.pl@input=blah in Windows mode.

Answer (score 1):

Your browser will view it fine if you use an URL like

```
file:///tmp/example.com/post.php%3Fid=1.html
```

instead of

```
file:///tmp/example.com/post.php?id=1.html
```

Note: if you're having trouble with internal links from downloaded files, it'd be because you terminated wget before it was done with the downloading. Since you specified --convert-links and --html-extension (only applies when those are given), wget would normally fix the links to use %3F instead of ?; however, it does this at the end, after it's finished downloading; if it has been interrupted, it will not have fixed any of the links, and you're left in this predicament. Of course, you can always write a script to go through and fix the links, but...

Comment: this is not quite correct, wget, with no interruption, for a URL like `http://site.com/article.cgi?25` will be saved as `article.cgi?25.html` see section 2.7 at http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#HTTP-Options

Answer (score -2):

wget does not have an option to modify the saved name.  What you'll probably need to do is create a script to go through and replace ? with _ or something similar.  Wget alone cannot do this.